# How do I parse text in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

If my selected fields contain the word "xxx" or "yyy", I want to change those fields to show only those words.  If a field doesn't contain either, I want to delete the info in that field.

How can this be done in excel?

Comment: You're thinking of doing this in a macro?  Or with expressions in other fields?

Comment: Honestly, I just started using Excel, so I don't know how to use macros or expressions, but I'm a quick learner. If you just point me in the right direction, I'll figure it out.

Comment: How much control do you have over the layout and design of the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use an IF expression here.

For example:

`=IF(OR(A1="xxx",A1="yyy"),A1,"no")`

If in column A you place xxx, yyy, zzz each in their own row. Then in column B you place this formula and replicate it down to row B3 you should find that if "xxx" or "yyy" is present in the cell then the value is displayed, otherwise "no" is displayed. You could change no in the formula to an empty string `""` to get the effect of deleting the contents.

For further reading on the Excel IF expression see http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php

Answer (score 0):

The worksheet formula you would use to determine if the cell 'contains' xxx or yyy, then perform the action you requested would be:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("xxx",A1))),"xxx",IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("yyy",A1))),"yyy",""))
```

However I want to point out that, in this case, "xxx" will override "yyy" in the case where the cell value is, say, 'abcyyydefxxx'...the result would be "xxx".

If there is a chance that a cell could contain both of your strings, I will revise the formula to accommodate that.

Now, the A1's in the formula point at the cell you are checking.